# Why does this Python function run twice?

Tags: python

When I run this in Pycharm Community 2017.1.1, It executes twice

```
def site():

    while True:
        site = input("Which datacenter are you putting this in? (One at a time): ")
        if site == 'ASH' or site == 'Ashburn' or site == 'ASHBURN':
            core_ip = 'y.y.y.y'
            break
        elif site == 'CLT' or site == 'Charlotte' or site == 'CHARLOTTE':
            core_ip = 'x.x.x.x'
            break
        else:
            print ("That can't be it. Sorry, maybe you mistyped?")

    return core_ip

print (site())
```

output:

```
$ python3.5 site.py
Which datacenter are you putting this in? (One at a time): ASH
x.x.x.x
Which datacenter are you putting this in? (One at a time): CLT
y.y.y.y
```

But if I run it from the CLI, it runs perfectly

Comment: I don't know for pycharm, as I don't use it. But you could make your code simpler by doing `if site.lower() in ('ash', 'ashburn')` ... `elif site.lower() in ('clt', 'charlotte')`. 

Comment: Maybe it's messing the path somehow and causes Python to load it instead of the [site](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) module. Try renaming it to something else.

Comment: You do have a variable of the same name as your function, which is also a built in Python module, and your file is also `site.py`

Comment: First thing I'd do is to change the variable name site because it might conflict with the function name somehow (though unlikely).

Comment: Also I noticed in Jupyter IPython that quoting ASH (e.g. 'ASH') makes a difference.

Comment: So, a couple of things:
@zmo - Good suggestion. I implemented that
 address the naming issue, I change the function to site_ip. I then deleted the sites.py file and rebuilt it as find_core_ip.py and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Resolved in comments**
>       So, a couple of things: @zmo - Good suggestion. I implemented that address the naming issue, I change the function to site_ip. I then deleted the sites.py file and rebuilt it as find_core_ip.py and now it works. – Steve B